# Fitting my table into tex width in elsarticle

Tags: tables, textwidth

I am working on a paper to be submitted to Esevier Journal and I have a problem with fitting the table int the text width which exceeds the text width. I'll give the MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\journal{Journal of Transportation Research, Part E}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}



\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}


\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec: intro}
Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text
Text textText textText textText textText text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
\begin{table}[H]
    \caption{Computational Results: Case I, $P_{1}$}
    \label{tab: Case I, P1}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
            Weight Legend & AVG. Time $(s)$ & Cost ($\$1E6$) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Risk (pp $1E6$)}  & No. of Trains\\ \hline
            {} & {}  & {} & X & Y & {} \\ \hline
            Case A: $\alpha = 1.00$ , $\beta = 0.00$& 2.06  & 0.96 & 1.80 & 2.16 & 19 \\ \hline
            Case B: $\alpha = 0.90$ , $\beta = 0.10$ & 39.8  & 0.97 & 1.75 & 2.13 & 19 \\ \hline
            Case C: $\alpha = 0.80$ , $\beta = 0.20$ & 53.06  & 0.97 & 1.75 & 2.13 & 19 \\ \hline
            Case D: $\alpha = 0.70$ , $\beta = 0.30$ & 44.72  & 1.01 & 1.75 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
            Case E: $\alpha = 0.60$ , $\beta = 0.40$ & 40.92  & 1.12 & 1.75 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
            Case F: $\alpha = 0.50$ , $\beta = 0.50$ & 39.8  & 1.12 & 1.67 &1.93  & 23 \\ \hline
            Case G: $\alpha = 0.40$ , $\beta = 0.60$ & 36.22  & 1.12 & 1.67 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
            Case H: $\alpha = 0.30$ , $\beta = 0.70$ & 41.21  & 1.12 & 1.67 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
            Case I: $\alpha = 0.20$ , $\beta = 0.80$ & 34.43  & 1.20 & 1.60 & 1.93 & 26 \\ \hline
            Case J: $\alpha = 0.10$ , $\beta = 0.90$ & 32.87  & 1.25 & 1.60 & 1.91 & 28 \\ \hline
            Case K: $\alpha = 0.00$ , $\beta = 1.00$ & 17.96  & 1.62 & 1.60 & 1.91 & 41 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{table} 
\justify Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text
Text textText textText textText textText text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate if you could help me out with fitting the table into the text width block.

Comment: I can't compile your MWE (missing `\begin{document}`/`\end{document}` and other errors). Also, please indent the code by four spaces in order to display it in a code listing.

Comment: i just format your code for you. please leave it now as it is.

Comment: I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

[image]

**edit:**

- your table has to wide column headers. to make them shorter i suggest to broke them into two lines by help of macro `makecell` from the package `makecell`
- for better formatting of numbers (aligning at decimal point)  i suggest to use the column type `S` from package `siunitx`
- the packages `url` and `hyperref` should be the loaded the last in preamble
- in the second example i show an alternative in which is:

  - reorganized your first column in three columns with headers "case", "$\alpha$" and "$\beta$"
  - for part of columns headers are in `multirow` cells
  - removed vertical lines
  - instead of `\hline`s used rules from ˙the package `booktabs`

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}

%\usepackage{lineno}
%\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of Transportation Research, Part E}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}  % new
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{array}    % loaded by makecell and/or by tabularx
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec: intro}
Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text
Text textText textText textText textText text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Computational Results: Case I, $P_{1}$}
    \label{tab: Case I, P1}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c| S[table-format=2.2]|
                       *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]|}
                            S[table-format=2.0]|}
        \hline
        Weight Legend
            & {\makecell{AVG.\\ Time $(s)$}}
                & {\makecell{Cost\\ ($\$1E6$)}}
                    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\makecell{Risk\\ (persons $1E6$)}}
                        & {\makecell{No. of\\ Trains}}                              \\  \hline
        Cases   &   &   & {Propane} & {Butane}  &                                       \\  \hline
        A: $\alpha = 1.00$ , $\beta = 0.00$ &  2.06  & 0.96 & 1.80 & 2.16 & 19 \\ \hline
        B: $\alpha = 0.90$ , $\beta = 0.10$ & 39.8   & 0.97 & 1.75 & 2.13 & 19 \\ \hline
        C: $\alpha = 0.80$ , $\beta = 0.20$ & 53.06  & 0.97 & 1.75 & 2.13 & 19 \\ \hline
        D: $\alpha = 0.70$ , $\beta = 0.30$ & 44.72  & 1.01 & 1.75 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
        E: $\alpha = 0.60$ , $\beta = 0.40$ & 40.92  & 1.12 & 1.75 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
        F: $\alpha = 0.50$ , $\beta = 0.50$ & 39.8   & 1.12 & 1.67 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
        G: $\alpha = 0.40$ , $\beta = 0.60$ & 36.22  & 1.12 & 1.67 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
        H: $\alpha = 0.30$ , $\beta = 0.70$ & 41.21  & 1.12 & 1.67 & 1.93 & 23 \\ \hline
        I: $\alpha = 0.20$ , $\beta = 0.80$ & 34.43  & 1.20 & 1.60 & 1.93 & 26 \\ \hline
        J: $\alpha = 0.10$ , $\beta = 0.90$ & 32.87  & 1.25 & 1.60 & 1.91 & 28 \\ \hline
        K: $\alpha = 0.00$ , $\beta = 1.00$ & 17.96  & 1.62 & 1.60 & 1.91 & 41 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text
Text textText textText textText textText text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
\end{document}
```

**addendum:**
or like this (as i prefer):

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint]{elsarticle}
%\documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{elsarticle}

%\usepackage{lineno}
%\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of Transportation Research, Part E}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% \numberwithin{equation}{subsection}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\usepackage{url}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}

%% `Elsevier LaTeX' style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}\label{sec: intro}
Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text
Text textText textText textText textText text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
\begin{table}[htb]
    \caption{Computational Results: Case I, $P_{1}$}
    \label{tab: Case I, P1}
    \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c
                        *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]}
                             S[table-format=2.2] 
                        *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}
                             S[table-format=2.0]
                       }
        \toprule
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{Weight Legend}
                    & {\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{AVG.\\ Time $(s)$}}}
                        & {\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Cost\\ ($\$1E6$)}}}
                            & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Risk (persons $1E6$)}}
                                & {\multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{No. of\\ Trains}}} \\
        \cmidrule{1-3}
        \cmidrule{6-7}
        Case & {$\alpha$} & {$\beta$}&  &   & {Propane} & {Butane}  & \\
        \midrule
        A   & 1.00  & 0.00  &  2.06 & 0.96  & 1.80  & 2.16  & 19  \\
        B   & 0.90  & 0.10  & 39.8  & 0.97  & 1.75  & 2.13  & 19  \\
        C   & 0.80  & 0.20  & 53.06 & 0.97  & 1.75  & 2.13  & 19  \\
        D   & 0.70  & 0.30  & 44.72 & 1.01  & 1.75  & 1.93  & 23  \\
        E   & 0.60  & 0.40  & 40.92 & 1.12  & 1.75  & 1.93  & 23  \\
        F   & 0.50  & 0.50  & 39.8  & 1.12  & 1.67  & 1.93  & 23  \\
        G   & 0.40  & 0.60  & 36.22 & 1.12  & 1.67  & 1.93  & 23  \\
        H   & 0.30  & 0.70  & 41.21 & 1.12  & 1.67  & 1.93  & 23  \\
        I   & 0.20  & 0.80  & 34.43 & 1.20  & 1.60  & 1.93  & 26  \\
        J   & 0.10  & 0.90  & 32.87 & 1.25  & 1.60  & 1.91  & 28  \\
        K   & 0.0  & 01.00  & 17.96 & 1.62  & 1.60  & 1.91  & 41  \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText text
Text textText textText textText textText text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Zarko, I appreciate your reply. I really like the output, however, I cannot compile the code!

Comment: @B.Bornay, you should provide more information why not.

Comment: line 1: Two \documentclass or \documentstyle commands. \documentclass[preprint, authoryear]{
line 47: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (S): `c' used. S[table-format=2.0]|}
line 47: Package array Error: Illegal pream-token ([): `c' used. S[table-format=2.0]|}

and etc.

Comment: than you change my mwe. it works as it is.

Comment: Zarko,  I did copy & paste your mwe, then tried to compile it, but errors popped up!

Comment: this is not possible to happen. for example, my mwe has only one `\documentclass`, loaded is package `siunitx` for `S` column type, etc. also i test bot examples and in my answer provide images of tests result (which are without any error and warnings or bad boxes. see added explanation in answer.